# How to use java.nio.file package in android?

Tags: java, android, java-7, nio, file-manager

I want to create a file manager application for Android using java.nio.file API which is the part of JDK7. I think this (java.noi.file)API contains easy solutions to design file manager application where JDK6(IO) and apache commons IO API does not have the same facility.

Please give some solution, how I use the JDK7 (IO) in android application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

**Originally**: the simple answer was that you can't do it.  Android is Java 6 based, and (AFAIK) there is no backport of Java 7's `java.nio.file` classes to Android.

(That's not surprising.  Porting `java.nio.file` would entail significant changes to the Davlik VM's native code libraries.)

**Updated**: according to the Android [javadocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/package-summary), support for the `java.nio.file` package was added to Android in API level 26.  That corresponds to the Oreo release which came out in August 2017.

---

> Can you tell me that what API should I use for my requirements. ( My requirement is File operation like : Cut|copy|delete on files and directories);

Prior to Android 26, I suggest you just use the `java.io.File` class for things like making directories, renaming files, and so on, and then implement the "higher level" operations such as copying files and directory trees using `File.list()` and `FileInpuStream` or `FileOutputStream`.  You could possibly simplify some operations using classes such as the Apache commons `DirectoryWalker` `FileUtils` or Guava `Files`.

However, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here.  There are already existing "file manager" apps for Android.

Comment: hi, I'm wondering that since I cannot import nio.files and other project like okio also cannot find this package in IDE, but how's okio works eventruelly?Really confused, can you tell me why and how can I do this like okio?'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184599/how-to-import-java-nio-file-in-android'

Comment: @machinezhou - Well, that seems to say that someone was trying to compile Okio in Android Studio and failed.  Same as you.  Obviously you can compile and run Okio on a real Java(tm) platform.  That is what it is designed for!