# how to import java.nio.file in android

Tags: android, nio

[image]

I'm confused.Why okio cannot find this package in IDE and android cannot use this packgae based on '[How to use java.nio.file package in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981757/how-to-use-java-nio-file-package-in-android)', but okio still works?  How can I do this like okio?

Comment: Any Okio methods that use those classes presumably do not work on Android. AFAIK, Okio isn't compiled against an Android SDK, but rather a JDK.

Comment: so if okio can pass the compile, how can I do that? I've tried this, but it doesn't allow me pass.

Comment: "so if okio can pass the compile, how can I do that?" -- if that screenshot is from Android Studio, switch to a different IDE, and build a standard Java JAR.

Comment: you genius， thank you , I'll try your way.