# Jackson unable to load JDK7 types on Android

Tags: java, android, jackson, java-7, kotlin

I use Jackson 2.8.2 in my Android app to deserialize JSON. The deserialization itself works, however, I can see the following warning in the application log:

```
Unable to load JDK7 types (annotations, java.nio.file.Path): no Java7 support added
```

Proguard is disabled, `sourceCompatibility` is set to `'1.7'`. How can I add these seemingly missing types to my build?

Comment: Have you checked this - https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ext/Java7Support.java

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, your `sourceCompatibility` setting of `1.7` doesn't mean anything about the runtime environment, so it has no impact on this message.

This is purely a "*do these classes exist at the time Jackson initializes this class*" issue -- and they do **not** exist in some combination.  And maybe that is ok, if you do not use the Java 7 `java.nio.file.Path` class then you should have no issue with this logged **warning** message.  Because that is what this warning is about, Jackson supporting serialization/deserialization of this specific class.

Looking at [Android `java.nio.*` packages](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/package-summary.html), it does not have `java.nio.file.*` packages at **any** API level.  So that explains why you see the warning message.  And since you can't use `java.nio.file.Path` anyway, this isn't even a real issue other than an annoying logging message.

If this message is bothersome you can always set the Java Util Logging level for logger `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7Support` to be level `ERROR`.  Then you will no longer see these **warning** messages.

**More about the logged message:**

In Jackson 2.8.x this support for Java 7 class `java.nio.file.Path` is all loading from the same JAR file and is built-in.  One class dynamically checks if another can load without error:

```
Class<?> cls = Class.forName("com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl");
```

The only way this can fail is if something is stripping this class from the final set of classes.  Or one of these classes it depends on is missing from the runtime:

```
import java.beans.ConstructorProperties;
import java.beans.Transient;
import java.nio.file.Path;
```

If any of those are missing then you will see the logged error message.  So one of these is true:

- one or more of the JDK 7 classes are missing at runtime
- `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl` is missing at runtime

Neither of those causes are Jackson's fault, they are something about your runtime environment (i.e. they don't exist in Android API's), or Proguard stripping classes it doesn't think are used.

See also:

- [Android import java.nio.file.Files; cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24869323/android-import-java-nio-file-files-cannot-be-resolved)
- [How to use java.nio.file package in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981757/how-to-use-java-nio-file-package-in-android)
- [Android java.nio packages](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/package-summary.html)