# Unable to load JDK7 annotation types

Tags: android, eclipse, spring-boot, data-annotations

In my *spring-boot* application I've used some **model** classes and further I need to use the same classes in my *android application*. So I just export the model class to ***jar*** file and put into libs folder in android. I've used some **mongo-data annotations**(@Document, @Field, etc) in my model class, here my code

```
@Document(collection="time_table")
public class TimeTable implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private ObjectId id;
    @Field("day")
    private String day;
    @DBRef
    private List<Subjects> subjects;
    public TimeTable() {
        super();
    }
    public TimeTable(String day, List<Subjects> subjects) {
        super();
        this.day = day;
        this.setSubjects(subjects);
    }
    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(ObjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }
    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
    public List<Subjects> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }
    public void setSubjects(List<Subjects> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }

}
```

Here, I've used **Eclipse export feature** to convert the model classes into jar file. But in my android whenever I try to access the ***TimeTable*** class from the **jar** file it displays the error

> Unable to load JDK7 annotation types; will have to skip
>
> could not load Java7 Path class

*I'm using Jackson 2.7.3 to map those object*

if I changed the **Jackson version to 2.9.3**, the error will also be changed

> Unable to load JDK7 types (annotations, java.nio.file.Path): no Java7
> support added

so Is there any good way to fix this problem, OR is there any way to get rid those annotations while making jar files.

I've also referred this link [Jackson unable to load JDK7 types on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425594/jackson-unable-to-load-jdk7-types-on-android)
But I didn't get clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson unable to load JDK7 types on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425594/jackson-unable-to-load-jdk7-types-on-android)