# Unable to load JDK7 annotation types; will have to skip

Tags: android, jackson

**my question is different as I have actually seen this library in effect**

I am attempting to use jackson in android studio along with the retrofit library. however i get the following error.

```
Unable to load JDK7 annotation types; will have to skip
WARNING: could not load Java7 Path class
```

I have confirmed that I am using android sdk 26 with minimum sdk set to 23
java 7
and have imported jackson

```
 compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.4'
```

I have looked around a no one seems to have offered a solution as of yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson unable to load JDK7 types on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425594/jackson-unable-to-load-jdk7-types-on-android)

Comment: the issue is they hasnt been a answer

Answer (score 0):

have you made these imports in addition what you already have

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.5.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'
```

see [look at here](http://shmuelrosansky.com/jackson/android/2015/07/20/jackson-android/)