# how to fix 'no such algorithm ecdsa for provider bc' while creating new wallet file using web3j

Tags: android, web3-java

I am doing this on the latest version of the android studio and minimum SDK version is 15 dependencies:

```
> implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
> implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
> testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12' androidTestImplementation
> 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' androidTestImplementation
> 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' implementation
> 'org.web3j:core:4.2.0-android' implementation
> 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' implementation
> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.0' implementation
> "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2"
```

My code is:

```
public String createWallet() throws Exception {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath().toString();
        String fileName = WalletUtils.generateNewWalletFile("password", new File(path));
        return path + fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[you can check here!](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/828#issuecomment-451858088)

@serso gives a function "setupBouncyCastle()" that you have to put in your class and call it in onCreat. this replace the Android version of Bouncy Castle with the shipped one! like he said. ^^

Comment: I have done that and now i am getting this error "  W/Java7Support: Unable to load JDK7 types (annotations, java.nio.file.Path): no Java7 support added".
What should i do now ?

Comment: Idk for this but you can check here --> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425594/jackson-unable-to-load-jdk7-types-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

If you are preparing release build with minifyEnabled is true and facing this exception:

```
 java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: ECDSA for provider BC
```

Add these lines to pro-gurd

```
-dontwarn java8.util.**
-dontwarn jnr.posix.**
-dontwarn com.kenai.**

#-keep class org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509LDAPCertStoreSpi
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.x509.util.LDAPStoreHelper

-keepclassmembers class org.web3j.protocol.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.web3j.crypto.* { *; }

-keep class * extends org.web3j.abi.TypeReference
-keep class * extends org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Type

#-dontwarn java.lang.SafeVarargs
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**
```

Thanks [Mimo Saha](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/web3j/web3j/1238/662234819)